# How to get horizontal scrolling along with vertical scrolling for listview?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, scrollview

lists.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/fix_container"
>
<TableLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*">
    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv1"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv1"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv2"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv2"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv3"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv3"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv4"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv4"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv5"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv5"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv6"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv6"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv7"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv7"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv8"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv8"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv9"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv9"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv10"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv10"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv11"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv11"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv13"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv12"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv12"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv14"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv13"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv13"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv15"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv14"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv14"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv16"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv15"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv15"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have written listview like this

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/product_list_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/card_view_dispatch"/>
```

[image: In tablet data is coming like this]
[image: But in mobile data is coming like this]

I set the lists.xml in my CustomListAdapter.java

I have total 16 textviews in horizontal.

vertical scrolling is coming but horizontal scrolling is not coming.

So How to keep horizontal scrollview to display data properly in phone also. How can I do this.

If this is not the correct way. Please suggest me another way.
Please help me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you add the booth orientation to your linearLayoutManager ?

Comment: No. If i need to add, How can I?@AmineHarbaoui

Comment: @vishnu try using horixontal scrollview in item and nested scrollview in main file.. and in item layout make height wrap_content and all textview width to wrap_content

Comment: I did not get u. item in the sense? and main file in the sense? Please tell me clearly sir@VishvaDave

Comment: @vishnu item file of listview.. a row which is used in listview (may be your list.xml)and main file means a listview file itself

Comment: Just one other question you want the recycleview scroll on the both sides or the recycleview scroll horizontally and the item scroll vertically ?

Comment: @AmineHarbaoui may be he wants item to scroll horizontaly and recyclerview itself to scroll vertically.. so basically in both directions

Comment: You have to add a HorizontalScrollView to your item like @vishnu said

Comment: I have added horizontal scrollview to item then no data is set to listview. But still I was not added nestedscrolview to main file @VishvaDave

Comment: I have added nestedsrollview to the main file like this <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">  @VishvaDave

Comment: and added horizontal scrollview to itemfile like this.  <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >   But no data is displaying. please help me@VishvaDave

Answer (score 1):

You can try out this library [this](https://github.com/jeffreyliu8/Nested-RecyclerView)

Basically the concept for this is simple, you need to create a vertical recyclerview   and then add a horizontal recyclerview in the required positions.

I prefer Recyclerview over Listviews, its easy and memory efficient

Answer (score 0):

**Try this type of layout :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.e2logy.demoapplication.DemoActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                tools:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                tools:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:listitem="@layout/tmp2"/>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**My item file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        tools:background="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        tools:background="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        tools:background="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        tools:background="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        tools:background="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        tools:background="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        tools:background="@tools:sample/avatars" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am using listview but u have used recycler view. Do I need to change listview to recyclerview. If yes Do i need to change my adapter@Vishva Dave

Comment: @vishnu yes you need to use recyclerview for this purpose.. as recyclervirew allow horizontal list.. also there are many ways to convert to recyclerview search it out..

Answer (score -1):

Try a better library for this there are many.
This I common requirement so you can get a lot of examples.

Comment: can u help me with the library links